Node Thresholds in Network Flow Diagrams
Is there a flow network extension which allows one to place a threshold on a node and still permit algorithms to find the maximum flow through the network? An example would be as follows:
Given the network S --> A --> T, where S and T are the source and sink, respectively. Let a have a threshold value of 3: if the flow into A is less than 3, no flow will pass through; otherwise, it behaves as a normal node. In this example, if the S-A capacity is 2 and the A-T capacity is 5, the maximum flow would be 0. If the S-A capacity were 5 and the A-T capacity were 5, the maximum flow would be 5.
I have tried redirecting the flow through a buffer node and using lower bounds, but I can't get the behavior I seek.
EDIT: Updated example diagram: The nodes a, b, c, d, and e have thresholds of 2. Unlabelled edges have capacity 1. The thresholded maximum flow in this diagram should be 4, as opposed to the vanilla maximum flow which is 5.


Thank you for this note; I have updated the example to have the thresholds change the maximum flow.


Set the threshold on all nodes to be 0 ( i.e. all nodes are 'normal' )
Apply the usual algorithm
Loop over nodes

IF flow through node less than the node's threshold

Remove flow through node and the node
Restart loop over remaining nodes




Apply the usual algorithm again to the graph without the nodes that were removed


I am concerned that this does not always find the maximum flow. If we are just removing nodes and rerolling the algorithm, I feel that, if there are multiple paths the flow can take, removing a node can push us into a situation in which we don't have the maximum flow available anymore.
